# Запуск screen и python на нем при запуске сервера (Ubuntu 18)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер, ssh, gnu-screen

Как сделать чтобы при запуске сервера запускался screen и python3 скрипт в нём? 
   (Ubuntu 18)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=screen+rc.local

Comment: используйте systemd service. куда эти архаизмы)